# Adding static route through group policy

Tags: route

We are trying to add a static route across all of our end user machines, we have setup a GPO object under Computer configuration > Policies > Windows Settings > Scripts (startup/shutdown) > Startup.

The command in the batch file is: 
route add 172.17.10.0 mask 255.255.0.0 172.16.12.100 -p

We have then rebooted/forced group policy to update and upon running a 'route print' in command line there is no route added, however adding a route through command line works perfectly.

Comment: Have you test the script locally to make sure that the script is working?  Does gpresult say that the policy was applied?

Comment: Yes gpresult says that the policy is applied, the script has been run and does work

Comment: 1. The route should either be `172.17.0.0 mask 255.255.0.0` or 172.17.10.0 mask 255.255.255.0`. 2. Why not just add the route to the routing table on the Default Gateway?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to add the static route to the network devices the users are connecting to?

Comment: If you've solved this, please post and accept an answer so anyone who stumbles upon it in the future can benefit from it.

Comment: Also, if the machines otherwise configure via DHCP, I believe you can [add this route to the DHCP response](https://ral-arturo.org/2018/09/12/dhcp-static-route.html), with the caveat that the default route then also needs to be a static route.

Answer (score 4):

According to [some documentation I found](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc757323(v=ws.10).aspx),

> Routes added by using the -p option are stored in the registry under the following key:
>
> `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip \Parameters\PersistentRoutes`

Perhaps you could just use Group Policy Preferences to set the appropriate entries directly in the registry?

Comment: Hi Thank you for this, we have added the entries directly to the registry and they route is added in there however it doesn't show on the route table. one step closer.

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact same problem, and my solution was the easiest "if not silliest" thing you can think of.

All I had to do to make the script work using Group Policy was to add entire command inside quotes ("), so the command route add 172.17.10.0 mask 255.255.0.0 172.16.12.100 -p should be "route add 172.17.10.0 mask 255.255.0.0 172.16.12.100 -p"

Agree with joeqwerty comment about fixing the subnet or the network ID.

Comment: I just tested this and found that quotes are not needed around the one-line *route add* command.

Comment: Huh, tough to say if it makes a difference six years later, I don't even remember what OS I used for client/server testing. Nonetheless thanks for the comment and hope it helps anyone who is suffering from this.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, I know, but I just 'solved' this for my small, subdomain deployment.  I used a Group Policy Preference to create/update a Scheduled Task that periodically calls `%SystemDir%\route.exe add /p x.x.x.0 mask 255.255.255.0 y.y.y.y`, while running as a privileged user.

If I need to add a route, I can add another execute action to the task via the GPO and it will update eventually.  If I need to delete a route, I can change the action to run `route.exe delete` instead.

The `route.exe` command appears not to return a non-zero exit code if the route already exists (nor if deleting a route that does not exist), so the scheduled task does not appear to fail.

Not perfect, but good enough for my needs.  If you want more control – logging, etc – you could always schedule a batch file instead.

Answer (score 0):

it should be on this format

```
route add  -p 172.17.10.0 mask 255.255.255.0 172.16.12.100
```

or

```
route add  -p 172.17.0.0 mask 255.255.0.0 172.16.12.100
```